# Wordpress: assigning a single DIV different IDs on single.php and index.php returns 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, wordpress-theming

I'm modifying a Wordpress theme and have run into a design problem that requires me to use different IDs for a wrapper div on the single.php and index.php templates. The original div's opening tag, which exists in the header.php template, looks like this:

```
<div id="wrap" class="clearfix">
```

My attempted modification looks like this:

```
<div id="<?php if ( is_single() ) { 'single-wrap' } else { 'wrap' } ?>" class="clearfix">
```

I've also tried

```
<div id="<?php if ( is_single() ) { 'single-wrap' } elseif ( is_front_page() ) { 'wrap' } else { 'wrap' } ?>" class="clearfix">
```

and

```
<div id="<?php if ( is_single() ) { 'single-wrap' } elseif ( is_home() ) { 'wrap' } else { 'wrap' } ?>" class="clearfix">
```

None of these solutions have been successful. In fact, each one has broken the theme altogether, returning a 500 (Internal Server Error), specifying than an unexpected condition, (I assume, the php if statement I put in the ID attribute) while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Now, I've made simple Wordpress themes before, and so I understand how theme hierarchies work; I also am pretty good at Javascript and Python, so I understand programatic logic. Is this a syntactical problem with the PHP? Or is there something deeper that I'm missing, here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(Also, if it helps, the theme I'm trying to modify is [AJ Clarke's Tetris](http://www.wpexplorer.com/tetris-wordpress-theme/).)

I should also mention that the ID "single-wrap" is already defined in the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one you aren't echoing the IDs!

Try this:

```
<div id="<?php if ( is_single() ) { echo 'single-wrap'; } else { echo 'wrap'; } ?>" class="clearfix">
```

Also, many themes will add classes to the body element based on what type of page it is, eg `single`, `archive`, `home` etc.  You may be able to accomplish this by simply using the CSS selector `body.single #wrap` to override anything defined in `#wrap` that needs to change.

Comment: This did the trick! I actually had just realized that I hadn't echoed the strings. (I figured that since I'm not familiar with PHP it just must have been a syntax error.) It's always the most obvious mistakes that get us ^^ I also didn't that some Wordpress themes assign body classes based on template. Thanks!